# How to single out a cell in a JTable and change its properties without resetting the rest

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to change the properties of specific cells in a JTable. I'm able to change the foreground and background, but each time I change one it resets the others. This is the code I have:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class Main {
    static JTable table;
    static Color newColor = Color.white;
    static int rowToEdit = 0;
    static int columnToEdit = 0;
    static char bOrF = ' ';

    public static void Gui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window");
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        String[] columnNames = {"1","2","3"};
        Object[][] data = {
                {"A","B","C"},
                {"D","E","F"},
                {"H","I","J"}
        };

        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
                return false;
            }
        };

        table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane sPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new Renderer());
        panel.add(sPane);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(in.nextLine());
        changeCellColor(0,0,Color.red,'f');
        table.repaint();
        System.out.print(in.nextLine());
        changeCellColor(1,0,Color.yellow,'b');
        table.repaint();

    }
    public static void changeCellColor(int row, int column, Color color, char backgroundOrForeground){
        rowToEdit = row;
        columnToEdit = column;
        newColor = color;
        bOrF = backgroundOrForeground;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Gui();
    }
}
class Renderer implements TableCellRenderer{
    Main m = new Main();
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
         JTextField editor = new JTextField();
            if (value != null)
              editor.setText(value.toString());
            if(row==m.rowToEdit && column==m.columnToEdit){
                if (m.bOrF == 'b'){
                    editor.setBackground(m.newColor);
                }
                else if(m.bOrF == 'f'){
                    editor.setForeground(m.newColor);
                }
            }
            return editor;
    }

}
```

I push enter once and the first cell's text changes to red, like I wanted it to. When I push enter again, the second cell in the column's background changes to yellow, as I wanted, but the first cell's text goes back to the default black. How do I make it so changes are saved? Is there a better way to single out specific cells to change their properties?

Comment: Since you're using member variables (instead of local ones) each time you call changeCellColor you're overwriting the previous values that specify which cell is which color.  The whole table gets repainted so only the current values you have stored in newColor, rowToEdit, etc are applied when each cell gets rendered.

Comment: Maybe [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) will help you. It shows how you can render a cell differently based on the data in the cell.

Comment: A `TableCellRenderer` is a shared resource, that is, each cell in the table is rendered using the same instance of `TableCellRenderer` (for the specific data type). You need to reset the `TableCellRenderer` state EVERY time it's called, otherwise, it will still be setup to what ever state it was the last time it was used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Strings as the table's data you could keep an object that contains the info for each cell including the String to display, the Color, and whether the color is background or foreground. See below where I implemented CellInfo and use the info from that to render each cell.

```
public class Main {
    static JTable table;

    static CellInfo[][] data = {
            {new CellInfo("A"),new CellInfo("B"), new CellInfo("C")},
            {new CellInfo("D"),new CellInfo("E"), new CellInfo("F")},
            {new CellInfo("H"), new CellInfo("I"), new CellInfo("J")}
    };

    public static void Gui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window");
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        String[] columnNames = {"1","2","3"};


        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
                return false;
            }
        };

        table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane sPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new Renderer());
        panel.add(sPane);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(in.nextLine());
        changeCellColor(0,0,Color.red,'f');
        table.repaint();
        System.out.print(in.nextLine());
        changeCellColor(1,0,Color.yellow,'b');
        table.repaint();

    }

    public static void changeCellColor(int row, int column, Color color, char backgroundOrForeground){
        data[row][column].color = color;
        data[row][column].bOrF = backgroundOrForeground;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Gui();
    }
}

class Renderer implements TableCellRenderer{
    Main m = new Main();
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
         JTextField editor = new JTextField();
            if (value instanceof CellInfo)
            {
                CellInfo info = (CellInfo) value;
                editor.setText(info.display);

                if (info.bOrF == 'b'){
                    editor.setBackground(info.color);
                }
                else if(info.bOrF == 'f'){
                    editor.setForeground(info.color);
                }
            }
            return editor;
    }
}

class CellInfo
{
    String display;
    char bOrF = ' ';
    Color color = Color.black;

    public CellInfo(String display)
    {
        this.display = display;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setBorF(char bOrF)
    {
        this.bOrF = bOrF;
    }
}
```